# NBA defensive player of the year NOT an NBA all-defensive team?

Tags: nba, awards, defense

I wonder how could a winner of the NBA defensive player of the year award not being included in the first team all-defensive, like it happened to Leonard in 2016.

Comment: He was on the NBA all Defensive team in the 2015-16 season. [Here is a link to where you can see the NBA all Defensive teams](https://www.nba.com/history/awards/defensive-team)

Comment: The website I was looking on reported a completely different set of players..thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was possible before the 2013-14 NBA season, due to [NBA All-Defensive Team](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NBA_All-Defensive_Team) voting being done by coaches back then, and NBA Defensive Player of the Year voting being done by the media:

> Prior to the 2013–14 NBA season, voting was performed by the NBA head coaches, who were restricted from voting for players on their own team.
>
> [...]
>
> When the coaches were responsible for voting, there were occasionally inconsistencies between the All-Defensive Team and the NBA Defensive Player of the Year Award, which has been voted on by the media. On four occasions, the Defensive Player of the Year winner was not voted to the All-Defensive first team in the same year. Player of the Year winners Alvin Robertson (1986), Dikembe Mutombo (1995), Tyson Chandler (2012), Marc Gasol (2013) were instead named to the second team.

Also, as noted by Ginge, in 2016 Kawhi Leonard won the NBA Defensive Player of the Year award and was voted to the NBA All-Defensive First Team for the 2015-16 season.